# ~/.xinitrc and Xmodmap startup item fail to take effect on startup in mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint, xmodmap

In accordance with [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login) I have added

```
xmodmap ~/Documents/looseScripts/Xmodmap
```

to my `~/.xinitrc`. I have also created an item in "startup applications" with the command:

```
bash -c "xmodmap ~/Documents/looseScripts/Xmodmap"
```

, and set the delay  to 60 seconds. However, when I startup my right command key is not remaped. However, pasting either of these commands directly into the terminal remaps the right-command key and and achieves the desired 
effect. How do I make either of these commands actually take effect on startup?

I doubt that it's relevant, but here is `~/Documents/looseScripts/Xmodmap`:

```
clear Mod4
clear Control
keycode 134 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
keycode 37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 108 = Alt_R Meta_R Alt_R Meta_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 207 = NoSymbol Hyper_L NoSymbol Hyper_L
add Control = Control_R
add Control = Control_L
add Mod4 = Super_L
```

**Current workaround:**

I have added the text from inside the `~/.xinitrc` to my bashrc, so that it runs every time I start up my terminal. For some reason it does not have any trouble running here.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simply using the delay option in startup items does not work. I have do exactly as [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54157/how-do-i-set-xmodmap-on-login) says and use:

`bash -c "sleep 30;xmodmap ~/Documents/looseScripts/Xmodmap"`

instead of a delay. However, this isn't very elegant, as I have no idea why this works. As such, I'm hoping to accept an answer that is a bit less hacked-together.